# Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined ReactJs,Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just started to get familiar with Redux and I'm stuck on this error.I'm getting error Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined,On code below which is in component. :

```
const mapStateToProps = (item) => {
return {
    todos: item.todos,
    numberPerPage: item.numberPerPage,
    currentPage: item.currentPage
};
};
```

This is my Storage :

```
    const initialState = {
    todos: [],
    numberPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: 1
}

const reducer = (state =initialState, action) => {
    const { items, numberPerPage, currentPage } = state;
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [
                    ...items,
                    {
                        value: action.value,
                        checked: action.checked,
                        _id: action.id,
                    },
                ],
                currentPage: Math.ceil((items.length + 1) / numberPerPage)
            };
        case actionTypes.GET_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: action.items,
            };
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a default case in your reducer which is what causes the error.

When the reducer is initially set up, redux dispatches an `@@redux/INIT action` at which point of time your reducer returns `undefined` resulting in an error when you try to access the state value

Adding a default case to return state will overcome this issue and solve your problem

```
const reducer = (state =initialState, action) => {
    const { items, numberPerPage, currentPage } = state;
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [
                    ...items,
                    {
                        value: action.value,
                        checked: action.checked,
                        _id: action.id,
                    },
                ],
                currentPage: Math.ceil((items.length + 1) / numberPerPage)
            };
        case actionTypes.GET_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: action.items,
            };

        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation !